# ESP8266 - Parsing last char from a string

Tags: programming, esp8266, string, code-review, convert

I'm trying to parse the last character from the string of the reply from server and print them to serial monitor.

My arduino code:

```
// This will send the request to the server
  client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
           "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + 
           "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  delay(10);

  // Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to Serial
  while(client.available()){
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.print(line);
  }
```

My PHP page only shows the following though:

```
  Output: 1
  Watering: 1
```

I get the following output from my Serial Monitor:

```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Fri, 28 Apr 2017 19:27:40 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/7.1.1
  X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.1
  Content-Length: 9
  Connection: close
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

  Output: 1
  Watering: 1
```

I want to get the value of Output(In this case it's a 1), and Watering(Also a 1), etc...

Preferably store them in an int.

I tried using startsWith,endsWith,etc. but to no avail :(

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE.  Be sure to take the tour to see how this works and to earn a badge:  https://arduino.stackexchange.com/Tour

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an elemental programming question, not related to Arduino in any way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've converted the string to a char array and just checked if there is a 1 or a 0 at that region.

```
// Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to Serial
String line;
int value=0;
while(client.available()){
  line += client.readStringUntil('\r');
}
//Serial.print(line);
char charBuffer[line.length()+1];
line.toCharArray(charBuffer, line.length()+1);
for(int i=207;i<line.length()+1;i++)
{
  if(charBuffer[i] == '1')
  {
    value = charBuffer[i];
  }
  if(charBuffer[i] == '0')
  {
    value = charBuffer[i];
  }
  Serial.print(charBuffer[i]);
  //delay(20);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to copy the entire string to a buffer; `charAt` give you access to the internal String buffer.  Your method doesn't work for string shorter than 207 chars. Your method return **any** 1 or 0 in the string, not the last char in the string.

Comment: I know it doesn't work for anything shorter than 207 hence why I started to search for info at char 207 and above. charAt won't work properly because the server sends a different responce in the morning opposed to an evening. You didn't even understand this question in the first place and I've already posted a solution that works for me back in April.

Comment: Your code is also inefficient, both in time and space. You can read from `client` char by char **and** detect/print the last digit at the same time. No need to waste space holding the whole string. No need to make a second pass looking for the last digit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a String `s`, then `s.charAt(s.length() - 1)` give you that last char.

The function `length` gives you the number of chars in the string (not counting the '0' marker). The function `charAt` give you a single char at the position. The first char is at position 0.

For converting a single char digit `D` (0..9), you can use (`D` - '0').

Demo:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial);
  String s = "Watering: 1";
  char last = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
  Serial.println(last);
  int value = (int) (last - '0');
  Serial.println(value);
}

void loop() { 
}
```

Comment: As I've said previously the char position changes on an hourly basis and won't be in the same place so I need to string search for that integer. Also this was posted back in April..

Comment: @William.  Beg your pardon? Your question starts with *I'm trying to parse the last character from the string of the reply from server and print them to serial monitor."